# How to set RealMemory in slurm?

Tags: slurm

slurm.conf should set the RealMemory of nodes to a value less than or equal to the memory available in the node. Otherwise the node will be set to a drain state.

How do I know the memory that slurm gets from the OS and compares to RealMemory to determine if the node should be drained?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can run `slurmd -C`  on the compute node. From the [man page](https://slurm.schedmd.com/slurmd.html):

```
-C
Print actual hardware configuration and exit. The format of output is 
the same as used in slurm.conf to describe a node's configuration 
plus it's uptime.
```