# How is RealMemory (slurmd -C) calculated? Why does it differ from MemTotal?

Tags: slurm

The SLURM documentation says

> **RealMemory** 
> Size of real memory on the node in megabytes (e.g. "2048"). The default value is 1. Lowering **RealMemory** with the goal of setting aside some amount for the OS and not available for job allocations will not work as intended if Memory is not set as a consumable resource in **SelectTypeParameters**. So one of the *_Memory options need to be enabled for that goal to be accomplished. Also see **MemSpecLimit**.

In several places I have seen the recommendation to set this value equal to the value reported by `slurmd -C`, for example: [How to set RealMemory in slurm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49902372/how-to-set-realmemory-in-slurm)

However, I am confused about how this value is calculated and relates to other information, as for example `MemTotal` from `/proc/meminfo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RealMem is in MBs

```
slurmd -C
RealMemory=193086
```

MemTotal is in KBs

```
cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:     197721028 kB
```

Just divide MemTotal by 1024

`197721028 / 1024 = 193086`

Comment: Oh, wow! This seems correct! [According to the documentation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/slurm.conf.html#OPT_RealMemory), in the `slurm.conf` file, `RealMemory` is given in **Mega**Bytes, so it comes as a surprise that `slurmd -C` would return **Mebi**bytes. And `/proc/meminfo` seems to lying as well. It says `kB` for **kilo**bytes, but it seems in reality it's in `KB` / `KiB` **kibi**bytes.

Comment: So, just to be sure: Let's say I have a node with 32 GB with RAM. That is, `/proc/meminfo` reports `32761680 kB` in this particular case, and `slurmd -C` says `RealMemory=31993`. Can I put `RealMemory=32000` in the node configuration? I.e. is the value in the config also base-2 "mega" or is it SI (base-10) mega in this case?

Comment: gosh darn it https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s2-proc-meminfo

"While the file shows kilobytes (kB; 1 kB equals 1000 B), it is actually kibibytes (KiB; 1 KiB equals 1024 B). This imprecision in /proc/meminfo is known, but is not corrected due to legacy concerns - programs rely on /proc/meminfo to specify size with the "kB" string."